# "Almost all objects have property P" vs. "It is easy to test whether an object has property P"

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, pr.probability

I am interested in any relation between "almost all objects(from a universe) possessing a particular property P" versus "testing whether an object has property P being poly. time decidable".

My guess is that they are completely separate (that is, one doesn't imply the other). Am I missing something?

(Note: *Almost all* in the sense of probability)

PS: I am not sure whether the tag probability is appropriate here, sorry.

Comment: Almost all reals are irrational. But testing whether "$0$ if Golbach's Conjecture is true and $\sqrt 2$ if it is not" is irrational is not easy

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen How is that a property?

Comment: Almost all strings are not valid C programs that loop forever. But it's very, very hard to test this property.

Comment: @Acccumulation being rational is a property. H von E wants to test this property on a number that has a somewhat annoying definition and finds that it is hard. So one thing we can conclude that how hard it is to test a property of a given object depends at least in part on how the object is presented to you

Comment: @DanielWagner Isn't that halting problem?

Comment: @CyriacAntony It is indeed! As problems go, there are few practically interesting ones that are harder.

Comment: @DanielWagner Don't forget tiling!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

They are separate (assuming $P \ne NP$).  Consider the following property $P(x)$: $x$ is a $2n$-bit string, where either the first $n$ bits are not all zeros, or the last $n$ bits are a yes-instance of 3SAT.  It's clear that testing whether $x$ satisfies $P$ is NP-hard, yet almost all strings satisfy it: the density $\to 1$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Nice... anyway you don't need to assume P!=NP, just replace 3SAT by any problem known to not be in P, say an EXPTIME-complete problem

Comment: This proves one direction. The implication in other direction is intuitively wrong; So, this answer completes the picture.

Comment: @CyriacAntony For an explicit counterexample to the other direction, consider the set of strings of even length - easy to recognize, but neither it nor its complement is "almost everything." *(And this can be easily tweaked to a set of strings whose limsup frequency is 1 and whose liminf frequency is 0.)*

Answer (score 2):

A (counter)example from the recent research literature: [almost every simply typed $\lambda$-calculus term has a long $\beta$-reduction sequence](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.03886.pdf) (Asada et al., 2019), but this property is very hard to test, even if P = NP!

Asymptotically, almost every STLC term of order $k$ and length $n$ has reduction sequence length $(2\uparrow \uparrow (k - 1))^{\Theta(n)}$, where $2 \uparrow \uparrow n = 2^{2^{2^{...}}}$ is the exponential function iterated $n$ times. However, to test this property, the only way is to $\beta$-reduce this term and check the reduction sequence length. STLC is strongly normalizing, so it is certainly decidable, but apparently this will take at least $O((2\uparrow \uparrow (k-1))^{\Theta(n)})$ time in the worst case, assuming that each reduction step takes $O(1)$ time. Deciding this property is apparently not in P. In fact, it is in $k$-EXPTIME, so it is not in P even if P=NP!

In the other direction, it's trivial to show that the implication doesn't hold: it is easy to check if a STLC term has a polynomial-length reduction sequence, but almost no term has such a short reduction sequence.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite common for properties split numbers into "almost all" and "almost none" sets. For instance, almost none of Turing machines halt. Almost all real numbers are [normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number). Almost none of real number are algebraic.

Comment: This does not seem to answer the OP's question. Can you modify the answer to relate to the property of being testable in polynomial time?

Comment: And how do we know that almost no Turing machines halt? One of the known normal numbers is Chaitin constant - and if almost no Turing machines halt that constant would be almost zero, which isn't normal.

Comment: @HansOlsson: I used a notation for Turing machines for awhile for which most corruptions of interesting Turing machines looped forever.